# Use value from one excel file for another excel file's chart

Tags: excel, database, graph, import

hope you're having a good beginning of summer. 
This question is fairly simple, but I couldn't find the answer to it on google and I'm quite surprised.
What I want to do is, as the title says, use data from one excel file, where data gets constantly updated, to create a chart (that also updates dynamically when the data from the first file is updated with new data).
I don't want to have to open the file with the data or to import the data into the file where the chart is located (which is doable with VBA, but I'm trying to see if there's a way to do that without using VBA). 
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll refer to your two workbooks as the source book and the chart book.

Open both books and create the kind of chart you want in the chart book.  Then simply select your data from the source book just like you would normally.

For example, I created two workbooks called "Source Data" and "Mirror Sheet."

Here are the contents of "Source Data":
[image: Source Data Screenshot]

Then, I created a chart and formulas on "Mirror Sheet" and selected the data from "Source Data":
[image: Formula Example]
[image: Chart Example]

As you can see from the pictures, the reference formula will look something like ='[SourceWorkbookName]SourceSheetName'!CellAddress

Check out this link for more in-depth detail:
https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2447199&seqNum=2

Comment: That's what I thought, as I already did do that. I tried to do it at the office, but it wouldn't work. I thought I was crazy ahah.
Turns out it's because my office's excel is 2010 and that doesn't work with the 2010 version. In order to make it work, I need to have the two workbooks open in the same excel window.
Thanks for your help TempleGuard!

Comment: @EmanuelSpektor - Sorry that doesn't work with your specific case!  I did another quick search, and the poster of this Youtube video says his method is specific to Excel 2010:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YgCJb2FF-4

Essentially, he's using PasteSpecial > Paste Link to link the data between his two workbooks.  Maybe you could implement that on your chart sheet as the source data for the chart.